# Is this code secure? SQL users-password-salt login

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have one cuestion about this code, here is the sql code

```
if (select [Password] from People where Id = @uid) is null or (select [Salt] from People where Id = @uid) is null
    return 2
declare @pass varbinary(max), @salt varbinary(max)
set @pass=  CAST((select [Password] from People where Id= @uid) AS varbinary(max));
set @salt= CAST((select [Salt] from People where Id= @uid) AS varbinary(max));
if (HASHBYTES(''SHA2_512'', (@passw+@salt)) = @pass) 
    if(cast(getdate() as date) > (select Expires from People where Id= @uid)) return 3 else return 1
else 
    return 0
```

and my login code is

```
public static int GetStoredProcedureReturnValue(System.Data.Entity.Database db, string storedprocedure, params object[] parameters) {
    SqlParameter returned = new SqlParameter("@retval", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    string query = "exec @retval = " + storedprocedure;
    foreach (SqlParameter sp in parameters) {
        query = query + " @" + sp.ParameterName + ", ";
    }
    query = query.Remove(query.Length - 2);
    SqlParameter[] sqlp = new SqlParameter[parameters.Length + 1];
    sqlp[0] = returned;
    System.Array.Copy(parameters, 0, sqlp, 1, parameters.Length);
    db.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, sqlp);
    return (int)returned.Value;
}
public int ExecuteSqlCommandAndReturnValue(string storedprocedure, params object[] parameters) {
    return GetStoredProcedureReturnValue(Database, storedprocedure, parameters);
}
```

And in another class...

```
public bool CheckPassword(Object value) {
    try {
        int i = FixedContext.Instance.ExecuteSqlCommandAndReturnValue("sp_checklogin",
        new SqlParameter("uid", Id),
        new SqlParameter("passw", CryptoTools.BytesFromSecureString((SecureString)value)));
        if (i == 2) {
            throw new NewPasswordException();
        }
        if (i == 3) {
            throw new ExpiredPasswordException();
        }
        return 1 == i;
    }
    finally {
        ((SecureString)value).Dispose();
    }
}
```

I want to know if this is secure or is better to create sqlcommand to table directly. Im newbie in sql-client interaction and i need advices...

I tried to get the return value with 'Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(...)' but it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Just a thought ... why re-invent the wheel?  Why not use the built-in membership functionality in the .NET framework?

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about, can you explain me? Im so so newbie in EF

Comment: .NET includes built-in functionality to handle user authentication and authorization.  Is this a desktop application or a web based application?

Comment: Desktop app, how can i put in my POCO user class this way of auth?

Comment: @DrkDeveloper [re-invent the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) as in there are plenty of widely used and well tested authentication libraries... Building yet another one especially if you consider yourself "newbie in SQL client" very well can be considered reinventing...

Comment: I'm not sure if the membership system is a good choice in desktop applications.  It seems to be geared towards web applications.  But read this for more info: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3855.how-to-use-a-membership-provider-of-asp-net-in-winform-application.aspx

Comment: If the parameter name can be user provided `GetStoredProcedureReturnValue` has a sql injection vulnerability via `query + " @" + sp.ParameterName + ", ";` imagine what the value of `query` would be if you added a parameter named `example; DROP TABLE People; --`

Comment: Thank you, i go to read it. If membership isn't good, can you recomend one way to do?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, the parameter name isn't user provided, but if i don't find another way to do or library i will update that code for avoid sql injection. Thanks!

Comment: Technically speaking your code is vulnerable to sql injection. You receive a string as a parameter and eventually directly execute that code against your sql server. This is the exact definition of sql injection. You should instead set your commandtype = storedprocedure and set the command text to the value being passed in. For user authentication I would agree with the other about using the built in authentication.

Comment: Off-topic to SO? Should this be on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?